# How are images rendered onto the screen?

Tags: java, swing, buffer, render, draw

This might be a weird question but what is the right way to think about how images are projected onto the screen?
if we have an image already on the screen and we render another image onto the screen does the new image go ON TOP of the old one, thus making the old one not visible anymore. or does it go behind the old one thus making the new one not visible till we clear the screen off of the old one. 
I used to think that the new image goes on top of the old one, however, after working with buffers for a little bit (ie BufferedImage and BufferedStrategy) I come to think that is not the right way it happens.
so can someone please clarify this matter
thanks

Comment: Think of it like a painters canvas.  Each time you apply more paint, you paint over what was already there.

Comment: When dealing with buffers, the concept is the same, EXCEPT, you are dealing with whatever was last on THAT buffer...so the sequence could be out of date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can think of it like a painters canvas.  Every time you paint something new you are painting over the top of what is there.

When dealing with buffers, the process is the same, but know you are dealing with whatever was painted last to THAT buffer.

So if you have three buffers, [1] is on the screen, you are painting [2] which gets pushed to the screen, it doesn't have the content of [1], but what was ever painted to [2] when it was painted last...

So you have [1][2][3], then you have [2][3][1], then [3][1][2].  Each buffer will be out of date by at least two paint cycles.

This is why it's important to clear you buffers and rebuild them from scratch each time, as you don't know the last time a buffer was painted

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what and how you are drawing.

The screen "refreshes" itself at a certain rate, (for example 60 times a second). At that point whatever the graphics card has in its memory gets drawn.

There are lots of different ways of putting things into that graphics card memory though and they have different behaviour.

BufferedImage does not directly go to the screen. Instead it's "copied" into the graphics card and that is used to draw to the screen.

Swing hides all that away from you though - you just need to worry about the repaint and it will handle the rest. The actual handling of this comes from the `Control` you are using, for example `JButton`, `JPanel`, etc.

Comment: Yeah I know how swing makes it easy to paint, however, I've decided to start practicing some active rendering instead of counting on swing to do all my painting for me. ive been trying to draw things to the screen pixel by pixel using triple buffering, and that's what had me confused.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to do that? If it's for learning then that's cool but if you have an objective in mind you are almost certainly better off using a suitable library (for example one of the 2d or 3d graphics/game frameworks would do nicely).